# How to generate actually, draw a several walls(10-15) on randomly position at the beginning of the game with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

**strong text**
I try to do It but have some problems. And also need to know how to at the "randomly time"(This is important) again generate, draw circles like food? I do tank game, with classes. So can someone help?

```
    import random 
    import pygame  

    pygame.init()

    window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    screen = pygame.Surface((window.get_size()))
    bg = pygame.image.load('###')


    class Wall():
        def __init__(self, x_wall, y_wall, width_wall, height_wall):
            self.x_wall = x_wall  # random.randint(50, 750)
            self.y_wall = y_wall  # random.randint(50, 550)
            self.width_wall = width_wall
            self.height_wall = height_wall

        def draw(self, screen):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (3, 3, 3), (self.x_wall, self.y_wall, self.width_wall,
                                                 self.height_wall))


    while game:
        mills = clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game = False

        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: `blit` the background on the surface which is associated to the display. `window.blit(bg, (0, 0))`. You don't need  `screen` at all. Change `pygame.draw.rect(screen, ...)` to `pygame.draw.rect(window, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a list containing your random walls before your while loop:

```
walls=[]
for i in range(15):
    w=Wall(random.randint(50, 750), random.randint(50, 750), 100, 200)
    walls.append(w)
```

Then draw all the walls in every step of the game loop:

```
while game:
    #....

    for w in walls: 
        w.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Concerning having food appear at "random time", this can be done in many ways. An easy way would be to import time and create a variable last_food and a random variable secs_until_food and then inside the game loop do:

```
now = time.time() #current time in seconds
if now-last_food > secs_until_food:
    #Create food object
    #...
    last_food = now
    secs_until_food = random.randint(10,20)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but I have two additional questions, can you answer please

    (1) What value need to give for "last_food" variable and I created food class like a 
          wall, so I just draw food  in "if condition" food.draw() is it correct?

    (2) How I need to check that walls do not overlap each other or overlap with tanks?
          for example in circle I can check radius, but can you explain a little bit how to do 
          it?

Comment: @Courtesy You could for example set last_food to time.time() and secs_until_food to 0 before the loop to spawn the first food at the start of the game. Perhaps having a single list of all objects to draw each frame would be easier, it could contain both food and walls. For (2) google "collision dection". If you are new to programming and your game is top-down game I recommend using a matrix to keep track of the walls to make things easier.